# i have problem in creating custom cfg parser , to check if a given code has syntax error or no using NLP (NLTK)

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

```
# Define the CFG for a Python for loop
for_loop_grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring("""
    S -> 'for' VAR 'in' RANGE ':' BODY
    VAR -> 'i' | 'j' | 'k' | 'l' | 'm' | 'n'
    RANGE -> 'range' '(' NUM NUM'*' ')'
    BODY -> STMT 
    STMT -> 'print(' VAR ')'
    NUM -> '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9'
    NUM -> NUM NUM
""")

def check_syntax(code):
    # Parse the code using the CFG
    parser = nltk.ChartParser(for_loop_grammar)
    try:
        parse_tree = next(parser.parse(code.split()))
        return "Valid syntax"
    except StopIteration:
        return "Invalid syntax"

# Test the function with some sample code
print(check_syntax("for i in range(5): print(i)"))
```

i have this code , my goal is to make a python program to check  if a given code has syntax error or no using NLP,
when i run the code i get this error "ValueError: Grammar does not cover some of the input words: "'range(5):print(i)'".

Comment: Probably the tokenization is not done correctly. Try giving the input with spaces: `for i in range ( 5 ) : print ( i )`

Comment: thx, now it compiles, but the code output invalid syntax , it should give valid syntax

Comment: Your rule for range has `NUM NUM '*'` for some reason, but your example has a single digit without *.

Comment: when i write * without '' , it gives me this error "ValueError: Unable to parse line 4: RANGE -> 'range' '(' NUM NUM* ')'
Expected a nonterminal, found: * ')'" , how can i fix the cfg to make it follow for loop syntax rules ?

Comment: You don't seem to understand your rules very well:  the rule `RANGE -> 'range' '(' NUM NUM'*' ')'` means that in order to form a valid `RANGE` non-terminal you need every part in it. So according to this rule a valid example would be `range ( 3 8 * )`, but the string `range ( 5 )` does not follow this rule.

Comment: how can i make NUM to be any  number formed from many digits ?

Comment: Oh ok this is what you were trying to do. You could do it like this for instance: 1) replace NUM with DIGIT in this rule: `DIGIT -> '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9'` 2) create 2 options for NUM: `NUM -> DIGIT NUM` and `NUM -> DIGIT` (the first rule is recurisve, it can add any number of digits; the second rule terminates the recursion). Of course the range rule should probably be: `RANGE -> 'range' '(' NUM `)'

Comment: thx that solved my problem , but between each digit there should be space , do you know where can i find more about cfg ? and nltk ? im trying to do a project that find if the given code is syntaxically correct or not , but i have hard time to find more about cfg

Comment: CFG are part of any [course about formal grammars](https://www.google.com/search?q=course+formal+grammars) (often with automata), it's commonly taught as a theoretical basic in a CS curriculum. It's also related to compiler theory. If you're trying to do a compiler for python, I don't think this is the most efficient way, but more importantly I'm not sure if you realize how complex the python language is? Or maybe you just want a subset

Comment: i just want a subset im not trying to do all the syntaxes but im trying to do if the user entered a wrong syntax i want the program to suggest a fix

Comment: You would need more than CFG to do this, because the CFG cannot find the problem by itself. I think modern systems do this with deep learning models, but it's much more complex.